# Android implementing OnTouch with OnLongClickListener ListView

Tags: android, listview, onlongclicklistener, ontouch

Im trying to combine ListViewRemovalAnimation (http://developer.android.com/shareables/devbytes/ListViewRemovalAnimation.zip) with Cell Dragging & Rearranging (http://developer.android.com/shareables/devbytes/ListViewDraggingAnimation.zip)

I'm trying to return false when a user holds a view down for x amount seconds in onTouch and thus calling LongClick.

However sliding to delete seems to work perfectly fine, but I can't seem to find a way to invoke the onLongClickListener when needed. I tried getting the difference in time between when a user first presses down on the view and the current time, but that didn't seem to work. I also thought about using a Handler with a runable, but I couldn't think of a way accomplish what I wanted.

I have a feeling I'm approaching this from the wrong angle, but any help to get swipe to delete with dragging and rearranging a listview would be appreciated :)

Here is the code for OnTouch:

```
public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
        time = event.getDownTime();
        if (mSwipeSlop < 0) {
            mSwipeSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(ListViewDraggingAnimation.this).
                    getScaledTouchSlop();
        }
        if(SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - time > 2000) {
            return false;
        }
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (mAnimating) {
                    // Multi-item swipes not handled
                    return false;
                }
                mItemPressed = true;
                mDownX = event.getX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                setSwipePosition(v, 0);
                mItemPressed = false;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                ifNameTaken.setText("debug69");
                if (mAnimating) {
                    return false;
                }
                float x = event.getX();
                if (isRuntimePostGingerbread()) {
                    x += v.getTranslationX();
                }
                float deltaX = x - mDownX;
                float deltaXAbs = Math.abs(deltaX);
                if (!mSwiping) {
                    if (deltaXAbs > mSwipeSlop) {
                        mSwiping = true;
                        listView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    }
                }
                if (mSwiping) {
                    setSwipePosition(v, deltaX);
                }
            }
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                if (mAnimating) {
                    return false;
                }
                // User let go - figure out whether to animate the view out, or back into place
                if (mSwiping) {
                    float x = event.getX();
                    if (isRuntimePostGingerbread()) {
                        x += v.getTranslationX();
                    }
                    float deltaX = x - mDownX;
                    float deltaXAbs = Math.abs(deltaX);
                    float fractionCovered;
                    float endX;
                    final boolean remove;
                    if (deltaXAbs > v.getWidth() / 4) {
                        // Greater than a quarter of the width - animate it out
                        fractionCovered = deltaXAbs / v.getWidth();
                        endX = deltaX < 0 ? -v.getWidth() : v.getWidth();
                        remove = true;
                    } else {
                        // Not far enough - animate it back
                        fractionCovered = 1 - (deltaXAbs / v.getWidth());
                        endX = 0;
                        remove = false;
                    }
                    // Animate position and alpha
                    long duration = (int) ((1 - fractionCovered) * SWIPE_DURATION);
                    animateSwipe(v, endX, duration, remove);
                } else {
                    mItemPressed = false;
                }
            }
            break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I also didn't edit any of the ListViewDraggingAnimation OnLongClick code.

**EDIT**: I tried putting the comparison between SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - event.getDownTime() > 2000 outside of the switch, thinking that Action_Down only executes when a user only presses down, but that still didn't return false. I think the problem may enly with the logic comparison itself

Answer (score 0):

Use Log.d() to check values of variables with logcat, sounds like you have problems testing.

onLongClick would be a function outside this onTouch function